# Mongodb nested if condition to get count

Tags: mongodb

I have list of task with different status(Completed,Closed,Accepted and New).I want get the response as like below:

**Output needed:**

```
["details":{ 
             "totalTask":10,
             "completed":2,
             "overDue":5,
             "wip":2,
             "closed":1,
}]
```

**Response after unwind:**

```
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d9fd84d3d598088d2ea5e0d"),
                "taskDetails" : [
                        {
                                "title" : "Tel Operation",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-27T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-27T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Accepted"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "KSCO",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Closed"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Daily Scheduler Maintenance",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Completed"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Daily Mails & Followups",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Completed"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Sales Operation",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "New"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Estate Operation",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "New"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Listing Operation",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Accepted"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Tell Operation",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Closed"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Data Processing",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Accepted"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "POC",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Completed"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Public  / Legal  Operation",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Closed"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Production Development",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "New"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Refresh Process & Hadoop Process",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "New"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Client Delivery",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "New"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Machine Reports & Maintenance",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-29T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-29T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Accepted"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Queue Check and Cleanup",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Accepted"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Production Report,Maintenance  & Followups",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-29T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-29T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "New"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Client Data Processing",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2016-04-28T04:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-04-28T13:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Completed"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Internet Failure",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2011-01-12T11:30:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2021-01-01T02:00:00Z"),
                                "status": "Closed"
                        },
                        {
                                "title" : "Power down",
                                "startDate" : ISODate("2011-01-12T01:00:00Z"),
                                "endDate" : ISODate("2020-12-31T15:30:00Z"),
                                "status": "New"
                        }
                ]
        }
]
```

For this i write  a query to get total and close,completed counts easily because they have in the collection itself.But for getting WIP and Overdue i have some logical problems.Both WIP and Overdue fall in between the **new and accepted** tasks.
**Conditon for WIP:**

Task endDate should be greater than or equal to give date(some date with matching condition)

**Conditon for Overdue:**

Task endDate should be lesser than or equal to give date(some date with matching condition)

**Query i tried:**

```
db.users.aggregate([ 
   { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("5d9fd84d3d598088d2ea5e0d"), "status": "active" } },
   {  
      $lookup:
        { 
            from:'tasks',
            let: { user_id: "$_id", start_date: ISODate("2018-07-02"), end_date: ISODate("2019-08-03")  }, 
            pipeline: [ 
                { 
                    $match: { 
                        $expr: { 
                            $and: [ 
                                {$or:[
                                        {$eq: ["$isActivity","0"]},
                                        {$eq: ["$isActivity","false"]}
                                    ]
                                },
                                {$or:[
                                    {$eq:["$creatorId", "$$user_id"]},
                                    {$eq:["$users.followers._id", "$$user_id"] },
                                    {$eq:["$users.assigned._id", "$$user_id"] }
                                ]}
                            ] 
                        } 
                    } 
                }, 
                { $project: { 
                    title: 1, status: 1, startDate: 1, endDate: 1, extendDate: 1, lastActivity:1,  _id: 1 }
                } 
            ],
            as:'taskInfo'
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$taskInfo"},
    {
        $match:{
            $or:[
                {'taskInfo.startDate':{$gte: ISODate("2018-07-02"), $lte: ISODate("2019-08-02")}}, 
                {'taskInfo.startDate':{$lte: ISODate("2018-07-02")}, 'taskInfo.endDate': {$gte: ISODate("2019-07-02")}},
                {'taskInfo.startDate':{$lte: ISODate("2018-07-02")}, 'taskInfo.endDate': {$gte: ISODate("2019-07-02")}, 'taskInfo.extendDate': {$gte: ISODate("2018-07-02")}}
               ]
        }
    },

    {"$group" : {
            '_id': {
                "user_id": "$_id"
            },                  
                    'Closed': {
                        "$sum": {
                            '$cond': [
                            {$and:[
                                {'$eq': ['$taskInfo.status', 'Closed']}
                            ]}, 1, 0]
                        }
                    },
                    'Completed': {
                        "$sum": {
                            '$cond': [
                            {$and:[
                                {'$eq': ['$taskInfo.status', 'Completed']}
                            ]}, 1, 0]
                        }
                    },
                    'WIP': {
                        "$sum": {
                            '$cond': [
                                {$and:[
                                    {'$ne': ['$taskInfo.status', ['Completed', 'Closed']]},
                                    {'$eq':['$taskInfo.extendDate', null]},
                                    {'$gte':['$taskInfo.endDate', ISODate("2019-08-02")]}
                                ]},
                                1, {'$cond': [{'$lte':['$taskInfo.extendDate', ISODate("2019-08-02")]},1,0]}
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    'OverDue': {
                        "$sum": {
                            '$cond': [
                                {$and:[
                                    {'$ne': ['$taskInfo.status', ['Completed', 'Closed']]},
                                    {'$lte':['$taskInfo.endDate', ISODate("2019-08-02")]}, 
                                    {'$eq':['$taskInfo.extendDate', null]}
                                ]}, 1, {'$cond': [{'$lte':['$taskInfo.extendDate', ISODate("2019-08-02")]},1,0]}
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    total: {$sum:{$cond:[{'$ne':['$taskInfo.title','']},1,0]}}
                    }
     },
     {
        $project: 
            {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Closed" : 1,
                "OverDue" : 1,
                "Completed" : 1,
                "WIP" : 1,              
                "total" : 1
            }
     }
]).pretty()
```

Some one help me to solve this.I have logical problem only look into my code and correct it.

Comment: Please Post your sample document

Comment: sample document is : Response after unwind .I am using lookup to get that result from that result only i want the output mentioned above.So, you can use that one

Comment: I am new to mongodb.so I am struggling a lot.Can you please help me